# CSS Media Print - Make table always appear on separate page

Tags: css, printing, html-table

Having two tables on a page that is going to be print, I would like that the second table is always print on a separate page.

For example: pages 1 and 2 contain the first table, and on page 2 the table ends right before the middle of the page.

Without any configuration, the second table would begin at page 2, right after the first table. What I want the second table to start on the next page (page 3) instead.

Answer (score 0):

page-break-before should do the trick - try  `#table2 {page-break-before: always;}` in your print styles